Fifth year PhD student with no progress on my thesis because of advisor, what to do?
I am currently in the fifth year of my PhD in theoretical physics at a reputable school in the USA. For the past three years, I have been working with my advisor on a highly mathematical topic that differs significantly from the more traditional physics research conducted by the rest of my department. I am my advisor's only student and their last student graduated last year. Despite being in my fifth year I have made minimal progress on my thesis.
I chose my advisor because I was interested in the field they are working in even though I knew little about it and after a few meetings with them they seemed to be reasonable. Having entered the program without a master's degree, I spent the first 12 to 18 months reading textbooks and familiarizing myself with the field. However, a little over a year ago, I began realizing that my advisor's ideas were unconventional and potentially flawed. I also noticed that my advisor contributed very little to their recent publications, which are all jointly written with other professors. This has raised concerns about my advisor's ability to advise me, as they often make fundamental errors that even graduate students would not be expected to make. I suspect there may be some health or personal issues affecting their performance, but I have refrained from asking them because I do not want to intrude on their personal life.
I feel that my growth as a physicist and researcher has come to a standstill ever since I stopped taking courses two years ago, instead most of my time has been spent trying to convince my advisor that their outlandish ideas are incorrect. It is almost like I am the advisor and they are the student. I have expressed my concerns multiple times, but my advisor responds defensively, placing the blame on my inability to understand their ideas, which other professors have also said are very strange.
I shared this with the director of graduate studies, who said they have also noticed strange ideas coming from my advisor and suggested that I seek a coadvisor. Unfortunately, no one at my university specializes in similar work. I have reached out to a few professors at other institutions, but they either do not respond or only work with graduate students from their own university. While I could talk to other professors at my institution, it would require a significant amount of time to learn a new research area, which makes me anxious given that I am already in my fifth year.
As a final option, I could try to write a thesis about a minor project I helped a postdoc with last year. However, my contributions to this work fall significantly short of typical PhD thesis standards, and the subject matter is far removed from my primary research interests. I am afraid how this will affect how I do on the postdoc market.
I am at a crossroads and unsure how to proceed with my PhD. Any advice on navigating this situation would be greatly appreciated.

‘It is almost like I am the advisor and they are the student,’ and ‘no progress on my thesis because of [my] advisor.’   I can see  a few likely issues here. Does your institution offer counseling?

@Aruralreader Counseling for students?

Most people who complete a very productive PhD in theoretical physics will not go on to do a post doc. Most who go on to do a post doc will not get an academic job afterwards. There are too few jobs and too many people interested in theoretical physics. See for example Is it still possible to get a decent job in academia (specifically physics) nowadays?
The brutal reality of that filter means you're probably not going on to an academic career at the point you enroll. If you've had less progress than typical at your stage, your odds have dropped precipitously from there.
Next steps I would suggest would be finding out where you actually stand with regards to graduation. Talk to the director of graduate studies (and, eventually, your advisor) and get some idea of whether what you've done so far can qualify you for a PhD degree. If so, your best bet may be to push on with that, get your degree, and look for jobs where people value the talents you've cultivated along the way. There is hopefully some sort of career counselling at your institution that will help you make connections between what you know and how you should sell that as a job seeker.
Another alternative to discuss with the director of graduate studies would be "mastering out" if your program allows. You'd get a master's degree that recognizes all the coursework you've put in. At that point you could also look for non-academic jobs or you can apply for PhD programs at institutions with faculty interested in the same areas of research that you are.
I do not think it's fair to ask someone not affiliated with your department to effectively take over mentorship while you're still your current advisor's mentee. There might be some rare circumstances where that's more appropriate (e.g.: advisor hit by a literal or figurative bus when you're on the brink of defending), but "no progress" is not one of those circumstances.
Changing research areas is another option, yes, but you should find out what rules for funding, etc would be at your institution and see if you'd have support to finish if you were willing to put in the time. I get that this makes you anxious, but none of your options are "good" options anymore: nothing will get you back any time that was wasted, that time is gone, so at this point you should be thinking about what makes best sense from your current situation forward. You won't be able to just think a little harder and come up with a solution that fixes the past.

Can you give evidence about the claims in your first paragraph? Specifically about theoretical physics?

@Buffy Added a link to a previous Q&A.

I think this answer captures most of what I want to say, and certainly there are not many good options left. Based on what the OP has said, they have tried being adversarial, they have tried finding different advisors, etc... All of that has failed. I would suggest another radical option. Try working closely with your advisor. Maybe their ideas aren't great, or maybe they are a stroke of unrecognized genius. Either way, what do you have to lose at this point? Seemingly your other options came up with nothing (external mentorship was never going to work, not sure why anyone would suggest that)

cont. so I guess one could walk away, or at least try to learn something from this person. You state that you feel you know more than them, and that's great, because most teenagers also know more than their parents. How about you see if you can glean something useful while having an open mind? What do you have to lose? I would say your two options (that you have left, based on what you have tried already) are either make it work, or master out (if that is an option).

Brutal but honest advice.

Due to my situation, my director has offered to secure funding for me through teaching assignments for at least three more semesters. What would be the better option between completing a subpar thesis with my current work or spending more time in the program with a new research direction?

@PhysicsTopic I don't think it's possible for anyone else to answer that for you. I can say 1) that it's most likely you will not have a life-long academic career, and 2) that if that's the case it's more important to be finished and awarded a degree than the specific contents of your thesis. The director of graduate studies is probably the person best able to answer with regards to what will be considered enough to finish, besides your advisor and committee who will ultimately make that decision.

Forgive me if I am ignorant of how it works in the US, but why do you feel the need to pursue what your advisor is pursuing? You are allowed to disagree with your advisor (at least I would hope so) and pursue another avenue - even if transpires that you were wrong in pursuing an alternative avenue, you are likely to learn a lot from that experience which I would argue is the point of a PhD. At a certain point, you have to take ownership of your PhD and pursue what you want to pursue (unless you are contractually obliged to follow what your supervisor is doing, for example, if its a condition of any funding you may have).
Your advisor may or may not support you in this process, but frankly given your current situation it sounds like you'd be better off regardless. My advisor is not a specialist in my field, so I do not get technical support from them. However, they do support me in writing my papers, thesis, with personal issues etc. So while it can be advantageous to have an advisor that knows the field, there are aspects of the PhD that can be supported by any advisor. If your current advisor is unwilling to support you if you pursue an alternative avenue, I would suggest finding a different advisor who can still support you in different aspects of your PhD and continue to specialise in what you're specialising in. Even if an alternative advisor does not know your field, they can still spot glaring errors in your work. Writing papers and submitting to journals for peer-review can also be invaluable in providing more specialised feedback on your work.

In certain fields you need to view your advisor concurrently as your supervisor. Most physics departments do this, the conventions in the subfield of theoretical physics may align closer to math/CS where there is a more casual advisor/advisee type relationship, but the departmental structure which governs how the student earns their degree is likely closer linked to experimental physics, which has a more top-down direct supervisor type relationship. Which also governs the disbursement of student stipend support.

My field is very deep so embarking on a research project without an expert's guidance would be difficult for me. I am not sure I could come up with a research question and answer it on my own without an advisor's help.

But you also claim that you feel 'you're the advisor and they're the student' so how can that be the case if you don't feel capable of pursuing a research question on your own? The PhD trains you to be able to become an independent researcher, and I feel in your 5th year, regardless of field you should be capable of that. You mentioned you did most of your learning for the first 18 months, and its only in the past year have you felt your advisors ideas are a little unconventional or potentially flawed. What were you doing in between?? Taking some personal responsibility may be required here.

Your situation closely resembles mine when I was getting a PhD in a theoretical field. In the end I was able to make it in 5.5 years with 3 publications, one of them being on the side project with another postdoc and another one being published already after I graduated. Despite quite stressful, my PhD taught me how to pose research questions and solve them independently, and I spent 4 more years in academia in a better position than my more lucky peers who had 7+ papers with their advisor's help. After that I went to industry, I continue to do and to publish research and I'm very happy with my current job.
I agree with other answers that the best strategy is to concentrate on fulfilling formal degree requirements, which you have to discuss with your department chair and your advisor. I would also suggest you to take some online courses on machine learning and to get programming skills if you don't have them yet. You can spend parts of your postdoc time for that too if needed. Postdoc is actually the worst job one may have, with low pay, bad work/life balance and quite low entry bar. Academia is really not the best place to work in for most people, and definitely not the most profitable.
